# Query with Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to build a query for fetching the events from the native calendar, i have stored description with 1 word from the these 3 words: "google", "yahoo", "stackoverflow"

For example: description="google",

As of now, i have made query as below:

```
Cursor eventCursor = getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),
        new String[] {"event_id", "title", "begin", "end", "allDay","description" }, "Calendars._id=" + calId,
        null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
```

now, **i would like to make query with Description part, how do i**?? of my current implementation is wrong, please show me a correct way as if you know !!!

### Update:

I have done so far:

```
public String Fetch_Events_Detail(long From_milliseconds, String kind_website)
 {
  String event_detail = null;

  Uri.Builder builder = calendar_events_URI.buildUpon();
        //long now1 = new Date().getTime();
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, From_milliseconds);
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, From_milliseconds + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);


       /* Cursor eventCursor = getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),
                new String[] {"event_id", "title", "begin", "end", "allDay","description" }, "Calendars._id=? and description = ?",
                new String[] { DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(calId),  DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(kind_website)}, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 
        */

        Cursor eventCursor = getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),
                new String[] {"event_id", "title", "begin", "end", "allDay","description" },"Calendars._id=" + calId,
                null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 

        if(eventCursor != null)
        {

         while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) 
         {
            String uid2 = eventCursor.getString(0);
            String event_title = eventCursor.getString(1);
            String event_start = eventCursor.getString(2);
            String event_description = eventCursor.getString(5);

            try
            {
                // SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                Date resultdate = new Date(Long.parseLong(event_start));

                event_detail=sdf.format(resultdate)+"  "+event_title;
                event_detail.trim();

                if(event_description.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(kind_website))
                { 
                 return event_detail;
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
             Log.i("Exception raised", "");
            }
          }
        }

        return null;
 }
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor eventCursor = getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),
        new String[] {"event_id", "title", "begin", "end", "allDay","description" }, "Calendars._id=? and description = ?",
        new String[] { DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(calId),  DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(description)}, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
```

Try this without calId

```
Cursor eventCursor = getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),
        new String[] {"event_id", "title", "begin", "end", "allDay","description" }, "description = ?",
        new String[] {DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(description)}, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
```

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanx for the great support, but pls check the code, it is showing an error regarding "]" bracket

Comment: @Pentium10 i have tried the above code, but it is returning nothing

Comment: What do you want to return and when? Do you have SQL knowledge?

Comment: @Pentium10 please, Just checkout the code at updated question, i have made your commented, so it is running fine, what i want to do is "I want to fetch the particular kind of website events from the native calendar ,say for example Google, the events i have stored inside the native calendar itself

Comment: Your script uses `calId` but that never gets a value, how that comes?

Comment: @Pentium10 I am apologize for the "CalId", i forgot to mention it, i have fetched it and i am having calendar ID, so having no worry about the same

Comment: @Pentium10 I am successful with the question code, but check above:  `if(event_description.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(kind_website))
                { 
                 return event_detail;` here i am comparing the value, i think it is not the best way, thats why i want to make the same inside the query from the calendar content provider
                }

Comment: Here can anyone tell me how to get event id. Which uses for delete any event?